# I am unable to see my tests in Test Explorer VS 2015 when creating CodedUI SpecFlow Tests

Tags: coded-ui-tests, specflow, test-explorer

I am unable to see my tests in Test Explorer VS 2015 when creating CodedUI SpecFlow Tests.

I have a CodedUI project that I have added SpecFlow into and unlike using a SpecFlow Project I am unable to see the SpecFlow tests to run in the Test Explorer.

This is all on a Windows 7 VS2015 Ultimate edition env.

I have created a .runsettings file as recommended for 2013.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow"/>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <specFlow>
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" generatorProvider="Specflow.CodedUI.MsTestCodedUiGeneratorProvider, Specflow.CodedUI" runtimeProvider="TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.MsTest2010RuntimeProvider, TechTalk.SpecFlow" />
    <!--  <unitTestProvider name="SpecRun" />-->
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
    <plugins>
    </plugins>
  </specFlow>
  <runtime>
    <assemblybinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentassembly>
        <assemblyidentity culture="neutral" name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework" publickeytoken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <bindingredirect newversion="14.0.0.0" oldversion="10.0.0.0"></bindingredirect>
        </assemblyidentity>
      </dependentassembly>
      <dependentassembly>
        <assemblyidentity culture="neutral" name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common" publickeytoken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <bindingredirect newversion="14.0.0.0" oldversion="10.0.0.0"></bindingredirect>
        </assemblyidentity>
      </dependentassembly>
      <dependentassembly>
        <assemblyidentity culture="neutral" name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension" publickeytoken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <bindingredirect newversion="14.0.0.0" oldversion="10.0.0.0"></bindingredirect>
        </assemblyidentity>
      </dependentassembly>
      <dependentassembly>
        <assemblyidentity culture="neutral" name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting" publickeytoken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <bindingredirect newversion="14.0.0.0" oldversion="10.0.0.0"></bindingredirect>
        </assemblyidentity>
      </dependentassembly>
      <dependentassembly>
        <assemblyidentity culture="neutral" name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework" publickeytoken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <bindingredirect newversion="14.0.0.0" oldversion="10.0.0.0"></bindingredirect>
        </assemblyidentity>
      </dependentassembly>
      <dependentassembly>
        <assemblyidentity culture="neutral" name="Microsoft.Services.TestTools.UITesting.Html" publickeytoken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
          <bindingredirect newversion="14.0.0.0" oldversion="10.0.0.0"></bindingredirect>
        </assemblyidentity>
      </dependentassembly>
    </assemblybinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"
        description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
      description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
  </RunSettings>
```

I have selected the Test settings file to point at this file.

Still hitting a brick wall when I build my solution locally.

Comment: I have now created a CodedUI Project and successfully added SpecFlow in from scratch, however I am still not seeing the SpecFlow tests I have created in the Test Explorer. The tests themselves are building and look all fine locally but are not appearing. Any help would be great!

Answer (score -1):

Now resolved this issue
If you have your project setup to save into your network folder not a local folder then Test Explorer does not trust/recognize the DLL the project creates on build and therefore will not display the tests.

If you have the project either saved onto your local drive (C or D) or alternatively get the network drive to be recognized as trusted.